Cartoon involving weird/alien creatures and a character who mutates to resemble them
There was some kind of team that dealt with these bizarre creatures. One of the characters was blonde-haired, younger than the rest, and would mutate to resemble the creatures. If they were plant things, he would start looking like a plant person. 
I think the team leader was a guy with black hair, maybe a scientist and there was definitely a woman on the team as well. 
The team also used a firetruck. 
I think it would have been around 2000-2008 in the USA, and may have been on Cartoon Network, but I'm not sure. 

Welcome to the community. That's not a lot of plot to go on. Any other plot details? I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

It's the cartoon based on the film Evolution.. 
Alienators: Evolution Continues
Blonde protagonist, Firetruck, Bizarre creatures, Scientist team. Also from the same time period. 
